# With React Native images disappear after some time when app is reloaded

Tags: android, react-native

When I include static images in my React Native apps (tested only on Android) everything works fine, also on a real device, *in the beginning*.  After some time, on the real device, when the app is reloaded, all images are gone (not visible).
I can reproduce this very easy, simply by creating a new project (react-native init myDemo) and then add some images, using code exactly as described in the Docs.
The code below is my code inserted into a plain new React Native app, and it suffers from the exact same problem (for all the images).

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',}}>
      <Image source={require("./img/blue.png")}/>
    </View>
    <View>
      <Image resizeMode="cover" source={require("./img/red.png")}/>
    </View>
    <View>
      <Image resizeMode="contain" source={require("./img/green.png")}/>
    </View>
    <View>
      <Image resizeMode="stretch" source={require("./img/orange.png")}/>
    </View>
    <Image style={{width: 51, height: 50}} source={require("./img/black.png")}/>
  </
```

View>
);

Is this a general Android problem with React Native, or am I missing something here?
Before you mark this a duplicate of other questions, if have tried the following suggestions from similar questions:

- android:largeHeap="true"
- Ad an eventListener to AppState.

Comment: hi, have you found a solution for this, i am experiencing it too

Answer (score 0):

my problem was simply with [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package that i had used to produce a unique identifier for the users that doesn't like to register.

I even had another problem with this package too. It made one of the reactNative apps on my device to logout automatically without any reason!

removing this package reverted everything to natural condition.

Hope this answer help you too.